# Apply appear function to elements created in ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a appear function which was created with this plugin https://github.com/bas2k/jquery.appear/ as follows

```js
/* ==================================================
 Animated Appear Element
 ================================================== */
DDDDD.fn.animatedAppear = function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
    $('.animated').appear(function() {
      var $element = $(this);
      var animation = $element.data('animation');
      var animationDelay = $element.data('delay');
      if ($element.hasClass('hiding')) {
        if (animationDelay) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $element.addClass(animation + " visible");
            $element.removeClass('hiding');
          }, animationDelay);
        } else {
          $element.addClass(animation + " visible");
          $element.removeClass('hiding');
        }
      }
    }, {
      accY: -50
    });

  } else {
    $('.animated').css('opacity', 1);
  }
};
```

I called `DDDD.fn.animatedAppear();` on `$(document).ready(function ()` which works fine with elements loaded with the page, but new elements created in ajax call doesn't have the animate appear effect, then I call `DDDD.fn.animatedAppear();` at the end of ajax success... it works with the new elements but also re-animates all elements on the page.

How do I remove the animate appear from already animated and appeared elements?

Here is an example of animated element

`<li class="item-thumbs span3 design animated fadeIn visible" data-animation="fadeIn"></li>`

and elements waiting to be animated are like this

`<li class="item-thumbs span3 design animated hiding" data-animation="fadeIn"></li>`

Comment: By rewriting the plugin to only act on selected elements and then using it properly by selecting elements for it to affect.

Comment: The link to the project is wrong, btw.

Comment: @Kevin B I have added the proper link to the jquery plugin I'm using

Comment: your custom plugin should follow the normal standards of jQuery plugins, including the usage of `return this.each(function () {/* plugin logic here */})` This change along with using `$(this)` instead of `$('.animated')` would fix most of your problems

Comment: Could you try if `$('.animated').not(':visible').appear( ... )` does the trick for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't, I think it has something to do with `data-animation="fadeIn"`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem all I have to do is set a delay and remove data-animation attribute and class fadeIn:

```js
/* ==================================================
     Animated Appear Element
     ================================================== */
DDDDD.fn.animatedAppear = function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
    $('.animated').appear(function() {
      var element = $(this);
      var animation = element.data('animation');
      var animationDelay = element.data('delay');
      if (element.hasClass('hiding')) {
        if (animationDelay) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            element.addClass(animation + " visible");
            element.removeClass('hiding');
          }, animationDelay);
        } else {
          element.addClass(animation + " visible");
          element.removeClass('hiding');
          setTimeout(function() {
            element.removeClass('fadeIn');
            element.removeAttr('data-animation');
          }, 1000);
        }
      } else {}
    }, {
      accY: -50
    });

  } else {
    $('.animated').css('opacity', 1);
  }
};
```